# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to resolve conflict between Serilog and Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, serilog

In my ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I installed Serilog. I never installed Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

But to my surprise, when I wanted to reference Serilog using:

```
using ILogger = Serilog.ILogger;

public class AuthController : BaseApiController
{
    private readonly ILogger<AuthController> _logger;
    private IAuthService _authService;

    public AuthController(ILogger<AuthController> logger, IAuthService authService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _authService = authService;
    }
}
```

ILogger automatically detect Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, and I couldn't change to Serilog.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.NET 6 by default turns on "implicit usings" ( `<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>`) in your `.csproj` file.  ASP.NET Core 6 by default includes `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`.

You can either 'disable' all "usings" or remove  `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` explicitly in your `.csproj` file.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Using Remove="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" />
</ItemGroup>
```

See [here](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2021/08/31/implicit-using-statements-in-net-6/) for more info.